# Ajax won't be reloaded properly every 3 seconds. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm trying to make it reload the partial that shows the number of messages unread every 3seconds.

But the codes I wrote won't show the numbers at all even if there's 1 unread message...
How can I reload partial that shows correct number of messages unread??

My codes are

### assets/javascript/refresh_messages_count.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // will call refreshPartial every 3 seconds
    setInterval(refreshPartial, 3000)
});

function refreshParital() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "messages/refresh_part";
  })
}
```

### messages_controller.rb

```
def refresh_part
    @message_count = current_user.mailbox.inbox(:read => false).count(:id, :distinct => true)
    # get whatever data you need to a variable named @data
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :action=>"refresh_part.js"}
    end
end
```

### views/layouts/_menu.html.erb

```
<span id="message_received_count">
  <%= render :partial => "layouts/message_received_count" %>
</span>
```

### views/layouts/_message_received_count.html.erb

```
<% if user_signed_in? && current_user.mailbox.inbox(:read => false).count(:id, :distinct => true) > 0 %>
  <li><%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-envelope"></i> ') + "Received" + sanitize(' <span class="badge badge-info">'+@message_count.to_s+'</span>'), messages_received_path  %> 
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li><%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-envelope"></i> ') + "Received", messages_received_path  %>
  </li>
```

### views/messages/refresh_part.js.erb

```
$('#message_received_count').html("#{escape_javascript(render 'layouts/messages_received_count', data: @message_count)}");
```

Comment: What do you see in your logs? Is `refresh_part` being called? What is shown in the logs as being rendered afterwards? BTW, your function is misspelt above (`refreshParital`)

Comment: @mccannf Thanks for pointing out my spelling. I revised and tried it again.  error log says SyntaxError: missing } after property list
 url: "messages/refresh_part";

Comment: Remove the `;` in your ajax call here: `url: "messages/refresh_part";`

Comment: @mccannf Thanks:) No more error there. But it still won't show the number '1' even if there's a unread message in inbox.

Comment: As per my first comment - please post your rails logs.

Comment: @mccannf It seemed there's no error. I doubt it that js is not even launching:(

Comment: Just FYI : Even if you are using traditional polling, you should preferably use the setTimeout technique : http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery (reasons mentioned in the article). Also, Check your javascript console in your browser to ensure that requests are being sent to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function refreshPartial to the following:

```
function refreshPartial() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/messages/refresh_part",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "script",
    success: function(data) {
             console.log("Called refresh_part");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert("Error: " + xhr.status + " " + thrownError);
    }
  });
}
```

(the `/` in front of messages is important, the other fields are useful as well - you can remove the success option once you get it working).

And change your method in your controller to:

```
def refresh_part
    @message_count = current_user.mailbox.inbox(:read => false).count(:id, :distinct => true)
    # get whatever data you need to a variable named @data
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
    end
end
```

(removing the `render` part - rails knows how to do this automatically).

*Edit*

After discussion - the last problem to be resolved was related to JQuery conflict - JQuery was being included in multiple places and stopping the $(document).ready from firing. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for help:) I tried your code but it still won't show '1' even though there's a message in inbox for sure.

Comment: Added error handling to ajax call - can you try? Can you confirm the success function is not logging "Called refresh_part" to the Javascript console of the web browser?

Comment: I tried it. Did you intend to make it popup when it's error? But nothing pops up:(

Comment: Is nothing been displayed in your JavaScript console on your browser?

Comment: I use web console to check them but nothing related to it appears here

Comment: There is a basic problem here. If you debug this (e.g. put a console.log() call into the start of refreshPartial), does it log to the console?

Comment: you mean refreshPartial in controller? or js??

Comment: I tried to put console.log()  in the 1st line of refresh_messages_count.js and checked my web console after loading page. But nothing related to this javascript appears in console:(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21527/discussion-between-mccannf-and-husten)